# Tidying up an Excel macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I have written a macro which goes through thousands of columns - because of this I end up with a very messy looking macro.

Here is an example:

```
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 78
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 385
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 539
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 770
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 923
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1077
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1385
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1461
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1615
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1923
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 2000
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 2153
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 2230
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 2307
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 2461
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 2614
```

These ActiveWindow.ScrollRow's don't look very tidy. Is there a way to avoid them?

Comment: None of the scrollrow lines are usually needed unless you need it to change the view.  Many times just referencing the cells directly will do what you need.

Comment: Just as Scott says. This is a common sight in recorded macros where you might scroll around to get to specific areas. 
Since the macro can do it without actually scrolling or even selecting cells, these can be modified after the recording is done. 
In this case, it's probably best to just delete all of the 'ScrollRow' lines. Especially since they will execute faster than can be seen anyway.